# Read and parse more than one text file matlab

Tags: matlab

I have four `.txt` files. Each one has 250 lines, where each line has 4 values separated by commas as shown below are the first 5 lines in one of the file, but all are of the same structure:

```
NaN,NaN,NaN,-1
792.98,419.48,333.35,245.63
787.13,408.59,345.05,251.48
798.3,414.17,333.36,245.63
803.61,414.43,333.35,239.78
```

One of the four files is the reference file, named `groundtruth.txt` I want to read each line from the three files and compare it with the values found in the same line number in the `groudtruth.txt` file. And after that save the difference between the values of the ground_truth and each one in a file for further processing, so the result will be that I'll have 3 new different files holding the differences where each file will have 250 lines and each line holds the difference such as the first line of the result file having the difference between the ground_truth and the first file will be like this :`79.8,9.42,22.35,10.63`
So if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should be the thing you are after:

```
groundtruth = dlmread('groundtruth.txt');

file1 = dlmread('file_01.txt');
file2 = dlmread('file_02.txt');
file3 = dlmread('file_03.txt');    

dlmwrite('diff_01.txt', file1 - groundtruth);
dlmwrite('diff_02.txt', file2 - groundtruth);
dlmwrite('diff_03.txt', file3 - groundtruth);
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks alot very efficient solution!! Thanks again @Marcin